# SingleSelection Mode for ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, xaml, selection

Is there any way to make a ItemsControl in WPF C# SingleSelect like in a ListBox?

Thanks

Comment: ListBox is an ItemsControl.  Why wouldn't you just use that since it already is single select?  You can make a ListBox display any arbitrary WPF objects, use a DataTemplate to form its items, etc.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to accept <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle><Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">

Comment: Well sure...the style needs to target the type ListBoxItem.  Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.itemcontainerstyle(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: If you are looking to put content in your ListBoxItems, use a DataTemplate, like this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx

Comment: The thing is i want the ListBoxItems to be ThreeState ToggleButtons where the ItemsSource is bound to the ToggleButton.Content property of the ToggleButton

Answer (score 0):

If you want selection just use a ListBox, that's what it is for. There should not be anything the ListBox cannot do what an ItemsControl can do.